# Multiple config.logger per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, papertrail-app

I'm using Rails 5 and I'm sending application logs to [papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/systems/stg_tx_app1/events/%22papertrail%22) using this snippet on my **environments/production.rb**

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  RemoteSyslogLogger.new(
    'logs6.papertrailapp.com', 41364,
    program: "rails-#{Rails.env}"
  )
)
```

Sometimes there's a delay sending out the logs to papertrail so I do `tail -f production.log` manually but it doesn't show anything since the logs were being sent to papertrail.

To view tailed logs I need to replace the **config.logger** with

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, "log", "#{Rails.env}.log")))
```

Is there a way in Rails I can use multiple logger in the same environment? Basically I want to send logs to papertrail or view logs manually using tailed logs?

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the Rails.logger with your custom logger:

```
syslog_logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  RemoteSyslogLogger.new(
    'logs6.papertrailapp.com', 41364,
    program: "rails-#{Rails.env}"
  )
)
Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(syslog_loger))
```

You can do that in an initializer file, or directly on your environment config file, however you prefer to do it.

Comment: @elyavarado. I tried to use this but when I extend the syslog_logger using Rails.logger.extend it doesn't send logs to papertrail, but when I assign it to config.logger of production.rb it sends the logs to papertrail.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda old question, but I just meet the same need, here how I've resolved it:

1. Created a LoggerProxy class to forward call to multiple loggers:

> ```
> class LoggerProxy
>   def initialize
>     @loggers = Set.new
>   end
>
>   def add(logger)
>     @loggers.add(logger)
>   end
>
>   def remove(logger)
>     @loggers.delete(logger)
>   end
>
>   def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
>     @loggers.each do |logger|
>       logger.public_send(name, *args, &block)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

2. In my configuration file, added my two loggers in the LoggerProxy:

> ```
> config.logger = LoggerProxy.new
> config.logger.add(Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}.log"), 10, 50.megabytes))
> config.logger.add(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)))
> ```